# Windows 2008 R2 DNS Server issue - Not saving changes for Transfer Zones

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, dns-hosting, dns-zone

I have a DNS server (Not AD) which is used for websites.
The problem is that whenever I change the settings in Zone Transfer and set "Only to server listed in NS tab" and restart the service the settings are gone. I tried to run it as administrator but the problem remains. I also created a new Server 2012R2 with DNS and restore the data. The problem still remains. I think that is something with registry.
Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the values from registry(HKLM->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->Windows NT->CurrentVersion->DNS Server->Zones). This is clearly a bug and Microsoft need to fix it.